# How to annotate an image with a polygon in Jquery, PHP and AJax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to annotate an image using Annotorious, but I can't see to be able to store it in the database. Also, it's not very flexible.

What I'm trying to do is draw a polygon or multiple polygons over areas of an image and store those annotations in my database (MySQL) and preview them at a later stage. I have spent days doing research but cannot figure it out.

Can someone please give me a guide or an example on how this can be achieved?
Thanks